# Re-run after_create callback on existing active record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, callback, product

I've recently refactored some code on and added a series of after_create callbacks to an  active record object called Product.  I've got a lot of Products in the production DB and don't want to go through by hand and re-create them. Is there anyway I can re-create all existing instances of an active record object through the rails console so that the after_create callback runs on each instance?

Comment: The callbacks are just methods. `Product.first.an_after_create_callback` should work. If the callback is private, use `send`. Please update with the model and the callback.

Answer (score 0):

from razvans comment I opened the Rails Console and ran

```
Product.all.each {|product| product.send(:call_back) }
```